# Communication between two java classes using Spring

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-integration, spring-messaging

I have two java classes that implements Runnable within the same application, let's say A and B classes.

These two classes share a BlockingQueue to pass some data. Class A sends data to class B through BlockingQueue. Then class B takes the data and process it. What I am trying to do is that when some conditions happen in class B as a result of process this data, it sends a messages to class A, and class A prints these messages.

So I was having a look at Spring messaging using Apache ActiveMQ, but it seems a broker must be started in order communication works using "activemq start" command. Is there any possibility to do this without having this broker started?

What is the best option to do this? I would like to do this using Spring framework so can be done using some kind of approach in Spring? Or the only possiblity using spring is through apache activemq?

Answer (score 1):

Take a looks at [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/); components communicate using `Message`s.

You can use an entirely in-memory configuration or provide persistence via some broker such as ActiveMQ.

The components themselves are not concerned with that; they simply send/receive messages.

Answer (score 0):

Create the Queue in spring and inject it into both Runnables

Comment: but using a queue to pass message is blocking, not asynchronous. I want that class waiting for message to be not blocked.

Comment: If it's waiting, how is not blocked?